# PHP solutions for storing forms in JSON

Tags: php, html, json, forms

Forgive my second-rate google-fu, but I'm finding this topic tricky to search for. All I can find is crappy form-generators that will pump out HTML.

I'm looking for a library or established approach to store forms (fields rather than form data) in JSON format. Is there either a open-source form-builder that takes simple input and makes JSON / associative arrays to represent raw HTML form fields or something like a standard for doing so?

something like,

```
{
    "id": {
        "Input": ["select"],
        "Name": ["favorite_color"],
        "Options": ["red","green","blue"]
    }
}
```

etc...

I know this sounds like a trivial problem, but I'd like to at least peak at an accepted solution before just rolling my own.

Comment: you do specify php solutions but all the same, the 2nd answer down on this post clearly shows someone else had the same thought as me, use jQuery to create the form elements on the client.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397926/loading-html-controls-from-json-in-jquery-i-e-reverse-of-ajax-serialisearray

#Accessibility issues aside of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically a templating system, using JSON as its intermediate language. Is there any reason you want to use JSON rather than one of the kajillions of templating systems out there?

Comment: I want to store user-generated forms in a databbase and use them in an existing application. It would make things delightfully simple to just plug this into a MySQL row as a chunk of JSON, but I'm open to alternatives.